# Devise Parameter Sanitizer "For" Method Not Found Rails 5

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I have just added devise to my shiny new Rails 5 app. All's good and dandy until I try to add a username to the Devise user model. Everything worked until I ran it and went to [localhost:3000/users/sign_up](http://localhost:3000/users/sign_up), where I was greeted by this error:

```
undefined method `for' for #<Devise::ParameterSanitizer:0x007fa0dc31c1b0> Did you mean? fork
```

I have searched the wonderful place of Google for any results, only being given outdated, Rails 4 errors and solutions, the same with searching Stack Overflow itself. I cannot get my mind to find a working solution. I would appreciate help very much. Here is how I prepared for this:

1. Create the migration: `rails generate migration add_username_to_users username:string:uniq`
2. Migrate the database `rake db:migrate`
3. Add strong parameters to the application controller `devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(..) }`
4. Add username parameters to the Devise views
5. Restart the server

Is there anything I missed or did wrong?

Comment: Did you try .permit method `devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit()`   The .for method is deprecated, now it is .permit from devise 4.1+

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The .for method is deprecated, from devise 4.1+ .permit method is available

Try `.permit.` It should work.

```
devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:my_action) { |u| u.permit(..) }
```

Hope this will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was well mentioned by @Shadow but this syntax worked for me:

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:first_name, :last_name, :email])
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:first_name, :last_name, :phone, :email, bank_attributes:
     [:bank_name, :bank_account]])   
end
```