# Devise::SessionsController (bug?) - Unpermitted parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, simple-form

I had the error that appears in [Devise Parameter Sanitizer "For" Method Not Found Rails 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38448598/devise-parameter-sanitizer-for-method-not-found-rails-5)

But after reading the solution a new error is appears in the console; I am trying to use simple_form with devise in **Ruby 2.3.3p222 and Rails 4.2.3**

Log:

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for ::1 at 2017-01-29 19:53:01 +0100
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"vIcpPg5diOGlDzcwYfEW+SEnY75IQPdCDvcoOzrbNMk4ezv8/f4wkhCLPdFbJ6E4RG19e1+ikif5/GLpQPH0HQ==", "user"=>{"name"=>"Mike", "surname"=>"Nast", "email"=>"mikenast@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`email` = 'josecr@gmail.com'  ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 25ms (ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"vIcpPg5diOGlDzcwYfEW+SEnY75IQPdCDvcoOzrbNMk4ezv8/f4wkhCLPdFbJ6E4RG19e1+ikif5/GLpQPH0HQ==", "user"=>{"name"=>"Mike", "surname"=>"Nast", "email"=>"mikenast@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
Unpermitted parameters: name, surname, password_confirmation
```

Also in my controller I have the:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
   prepend_before_action :require_no_authentication, only: [:new, :create, :cancel]
   prepend_before_action :authenticate_scope!, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
   prepend_before_action :set_minimum_password_length, only: [:new, :edit]

   before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

   def configure_permitted_parameters                 
     devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:name, :surname, :password_confirmation])                 
   end
```

In the sign_up view I have the following one:

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
              <p><br/>

     <%= f.error_notification %>

        <div class="wrapper wrapper-content  animated fadeInRight">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <div class="ibox">
                <div class="ibox-content">

                  <div class="form-inputs">
                    <%= f.input :name, :label => 'First Name', required: true, autofocus: true %>
                    <br>
                    <%= f.input :surname, :label => 'Last Name', required: true, autofocus: true %>
                    <br>
                    <%= f.input :email, :label => 'Email', required: true, autofocus: true %>
                    <br>
                    <%= f.input :password, :label => 'Password', required: true %>
                    <br>
                    <%= f.input :password_confirmation, :label => 'Confirm Password', required: true %>
                    <br>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-actions">
                    <%= f.button :submit, "Sign up" %>
                  </div>
                  <% end %>
```

Is there anything I missed or did wrong?

Comment: I guess :sign_up and :sign_in are two completely different devise actions. The log you posted seems to do with sign_in

Comment: Probably the url is wrong somewhere

Comment: I m trying to sign_up

Comment: Something is happen because when I use form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) , I can register the user but not with the simple_form_for

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is similar to another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45682243/4515413) which I tried to answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64682604/4515413)

Try replacing `:url => session_path(resource_name)` with `:url => registration_path(resource_name)` or the like - as specified in `devise/shared/_links.html.erb` file.